# AWS CodeBuild long waiting times in queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, aws-codebuild

I have a monorepo typescript project that I'm building with CodeBuild. At first I was running builds in a single build project, but having many issues building with monorepo tools (turborepo) I decided to build each workspace in separate build project on CodeBuild.

So let's say I have five build projects, each is downloading full code from the same git repo, but then each builds different part of code. All is working well, all builds starts at the same time via git webhook, but some of them are stuck in queue for like 10 to 15 minutes (build stage is about 2min long).

[image: example of long waiting time in queue]

Why is this happening and is there something I can do to prevent long waiting times?

Interesting thing is that I have something similar on other AWS account, where I run build projects in Code Pipeline. In build phase I run five parallel build jobs and max wait time in queue is less than 1m. The only difference I see is that on that other project I use old images (`aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0`) while on this current project I use new one (`aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0`).

[image: env config of current project]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, AWS sets limit for "new" accounts to just 1 concurrent build job. Regardless if builds are in same project or different, only one build job will run, others will wait in queue.

If you want to resolve that, you have to write to AWS support asking them to set  limits to defaults, which is 60 concurrent builds per region.